# How do it filter out my sqlite data using spinner?

Tags: android, listview, filter, android-spinner

here is my spinner activity :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.item_listview);

    myspinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnertype);

    ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.type_arrays,R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    myspinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    myspinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        (i assume its some kind of setfilter here)

        }


        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });

}
```

---

under my string resource file, i have about 5 items(all,fruits,meat,dairy,vege) as the dropdown spinner. 
i want the listview to appear everything when i pressed "all" and filter out other types when i pressed "fruits".

Do i need to create another custom adapter just for the spinner?

Answer (score 1):

I think you simply set the appropriate WHERE clause, redo the query for the ListView and then either use `yourListViewAdapter.swapCursor(yourcsr)` or `yourListViewAdapter.notiftDataSetChanged`, which will refresh the ListView.

If using an array for the ListView then add a step, if needed to, rebuild the array and use the notifyDataSetChanged (swapCursor can only be used if the csr is the source for the ListView).

e.g. (although this changes the adapter of another spinner (*spinner's and listviews are quire similar, in fact I use a single adapter for both in some cases*))

```
        shopspinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(
                new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view,
                                       int position, long rowid) {
                currentshopid = rowid;
                aislefilter = AISLESHOPREF_COLUMN + " = " +
                        Long.toString(currentshopid);
                alcsr = dbaislemethods.getAisles(aislefilter,aisleorderby);
                aislelistadapter.swapCursor(alcsr);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: thankyou for your code. i got the idea you are trying to tell me. i will work it out with my code